# From old-school redirect-after-post to modern ajax form handling

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

Up to now I mainly did old-school web form handling:

- redirect after post if the data is valid
- show the form again with errors if the data is not valid

I want to switch from this old-school way to modern ajax form submitting.

I see two ways for the client server dialog to transfer the status (post was successful or not):

1. HTTP-Status Code
2. JSON data

Is there a common way or even an internet standard how to handle form submitting via ajax?

Comment: Solution 1) Do the check in the front-side: the best is to integrate angularjs or another UI Framework just in the page, you can do it in jquery but it will be horrible code. 2) Use Ajax to submit the content of the form, if return code is 4XX then stay on the page, else redirect.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I  have not worked with AngularJS up to now. How would this work? Does the server send html-fragements to the AngularJS client? How to integrate django with AngularJS? Do you just take both parts, or do you take a glue part like this: http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html ?

Comment: guettli: You should use angular 1.4 instead of 2.0 (totally different). In 1.4, the rendering is 100% frontend. Angular is a js library, you have to include it with <script src="..../angular.min.js"></script>, you have to put "ng-app='MyApplication'" in the `<html>` tag, "ng-controller='MyController'" in the body tag, and in the js code you have to create both MyApplication and MyController. In the controller you put the code executed in the page, and you can use ng-repeat etc.. in the html file. You should try the angularjs examples.

Answer (score 2):

The common practice is to send both HTTP code and JSON payload, which can be error details for 4xx codes, or a redirect URL in case of success. Also, in the AJAX world, you don't have to redirect, you can just stay on the same page (usually giving the user some feedback about the successful action).

For example, in your backend you can have something like

```
@post('/change-password')
if not-logged-in
    return { status: 403, message: "Please log in" }
if post[old-password] != user.password
    return { status: 400, message: "Please enter the correct password" }
user.change-password(post[new-password])
return { status: 200, redirectURL: '/home' }
// or to stay on the same page:
return { status: 200, message: "Password updated!" }
```

and handle it like this on the client side:

```
    function success(json) {
        if(json.message)
            return showMessage(json.message)
        if(json.redirectURL)
            window.location.href = json.redirectURL
    }

    function error(xhr) {
        var json = xhr.responseJSON;
        showMessage(json.message)
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/change-password',
        data: {old-password: $(...).val(), new-password: $(...).val() },
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
```

Comment: I'd argue that 400, 403, and in fact *any* 4xx & 5xx code are semantically inappropriate for this case. Specifically 403 means forbidden and that's hardly representative of the type of problem.

Comment: @Amit: why? If someone is not logged in, 403 is a natural response to "/change-password" (or any other signed-in url).

Comment: But the question is about illegal data, not invalid state

Comment: @Amit: Yes, http response codes don't (and can't) describe every possible situation precisely, but in the rest/ajax world sending 200 if an action has clearly failed is conceptually wrong. In a lack of a better choice we return something that _roughly_ matches the circumstances (400 = invalid data, 403 = must be logged-in etc), and provide exact reason of the failure in the JSON payload.

Comment: Again, you're assuming things that are not in the question. The question is not about REST at all. It's about an unobtrusive handling of form posts (A-la SPA). Besides, even within the REST paradigm, using 4xx error codes only complicates client side handling. For example, in your code you assume the error includes a `responseJSON`, but if a real error occurred (even a 400 - Bad Request, and of course any other error as well), you'd have created an exception and no message will be shown. Using a success code makes life much simpler. You can assume valid JSON exist and simply branch by content.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTTP status codes is limiting and incorrect.

It's limiting since you can basically return success OR failure, but no details (for example, multiple fields failed...)

It's incorrect since [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) have well defined meanings, non of which are fitting for the purpose of invalid form data.

It's more useful to use JSON results where you can include all meaningful information for display.

Comment: 400 is pretty fitting in my opinion

Comment: @Paulpro - I'd say that's debatable perhaps, but I see "400 - Bad Request" as a literally bad request (for example, service expects posted JSON, but got urlencoded data, or malformed JSON...), not illegal data. The examples in wikipedia (as a somewhat credible reference) also lean towards this definition of "Bad Request".